# Center embedded Bokeh plot

Tags: python, css, bokeh

How can I center an embedded Bokeh plot? My css seems to have no effect on Bokeh's `<div class="plotdiv">`. In the minimal example below, I want the plot to be at the center of the yellow container.

```
from jinja2 import Template
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.util.browser import view

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1 = [0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 25, 28, 4, 7]

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.scatter(x1, y1, size=12, color="red", alpha=0.5)

script, div = components(p1)

template = Template('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>
        {{ js_resources }}
        {{ css_resources }}
        {{ script }}
    <style>
    .wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

    .plotdiv {
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        {{ div }}
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
''')

js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
css_resources = INLINE.render_css()

filename = 'embed_multiple.html'

html = template.render(js_resources=js_resources,
                       css_resources=css_resources,
                       script=script,
                       div=div)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

view(filename)
```

** The filler below is added only to appease SE's robot **

SE's robot wants me to add "more details" because this question is "mostly code." Hey, robot, the question is straightforward, and it's only "mostly code" because I did my homework and try to make it easier for people to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bokeh `0.11.1` changing to the following works for me:

```
.bk-plot-wrapper table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The issue is the the `div.bk-plot-wrapper` takes up all the space of the enclosing `<div>`. But the internal `<table>` that lays out the plot doesn't. I'm not a CSS expert, but maybe someone else can add more information

Two notes: I'm not sure what version of Bokeh you have, `.plotdiv` has not been in use for some time. Also please note that some foundational improvements to layout will be landing in `0.12` to make Bokeh much more respponsive and "webby" by default, and so the above code will probably not work with `0.12` (in particular, the `<table>` is going away).

Comment: It works! Many thanks. I'm using `0.11.1`, too. The `plotdiv` class is assigned to the [div generated by bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/embed.html) to be placed where you the plot on the page, so I was hoping I could just style that. I was not smart or patient enough to find out about the bk-plot-wrapper inside that massive JS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I think that might need to be updated.

Comment: Instead of styling the `table` inside, I style the `.bk-plot-wrapper` div with `display: table`, which keeps it from taking up all the available width. Hopefully, this will be more forward-compatible.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div align="center">put the bokeh plot here</div>
```