# Embedding Bokeh plots in wordpress post

Tags: python, wordpress, bokeh

I can generate and embed a bokeh plot in a post, but can't get the plot to align left (or center)

Plot generated using `autoload_static()` as shown here:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import autoload_static
from bokeh.resources import CDN


x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)

p = figure(width = 400, height = 400,
       title = 'Sample Figure')

p.circle(x, y, size = 10)

js, tag = autoload_static(model = p, resources = CDN, 
                      script_path = 'mysite/sample.js')

jsfile = open('sample.js', 'w')
jsfile.write(js)
jsfile.close

print(tag)
```

Then, uploading `sample.js` to the site, and pasting the tag into the wordpress post editor gives me this:

[embedded figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONF72.png)

How can I get the left edge of the figure to align with the left edge of the post?

Edit: Just saw this question

[Center embedded Bokeh plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222307/center-embedded-bokeh-plot), which I think is the same issue, but it's a bit over my head.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely certain myself but I have a couple ideas you can look into,

1) Check out: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed

2) I know it is possible to write posts in HTML on wordpress if you put the js content with *script* tags, from what I understand, it should embed the code.

Hope this helps.